# How To Allow Only Specific User Agent To Access a URL?

Tags: htaccess

Suppose this is my URL: `https://www.mrskt.com/sitemap_index.xml`

I want to only allow specific user agents. I mean only search bots like Google, Bing, Ahrefs, etc. can access that URL.

No other user agent can access that URL.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at aleast two ways you can block other user agents and allow only a few. This can be done by editing the .htaccess file in the root directory of your WordPress website.

#### Option 1

Using **mod_rewrite**, add the code below at the top of your **.htaccess** file.

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Google|Bing)
RewriteRule ^(sitemap_index\.xml)$ - [F,L]

</IfModule>
```

#### Option 2

This option uses the **mod_setenvif** module with **SetEnvIfNoCase** block incase **mod_rewrite** isn't available.
Add the code below at the top of your **.htaccess** file.

```xml
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* allowed_user_agents
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bing.* allowed_user_agents

Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch "^(sitemap_index\.xml)$">
Deny from all
Allow from env=allowed_user_agents
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

You could also [use robots.txt file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocking-of-robots), but I haven't tested this one yet.

Comment: The OP is wanting to restrict access to a specific URL. Both your examples restrict access to the entire site.

Comment: The code in my answer allows only specific user agents and blocks the rest as the OP is asking.

Comment: ... and to a specific URL, namely `/sitemap_index.xml`. (It doesn't make sense to restrict an entire site to "search bots" only.)

Comment: Hi but i want this only on specific url (https://www.mrskt.com/sitemap_index.xml) not the entire site, Please tell...

Comment: I have improved the code (see the modified answer above) so that only the `sitemap_index.xml` file is targeted. I have tested both and seem to work. Let me know if I have left anything out.

Comment: @Rodgath Now, It's Working Perfectly

Comment: @MrSKT, I'm glad that the solution worked. You may now mark the answer as accepted. Good day sir.